# PHP : why does imagepng() function increase the size when saving the image?

Tags: php, size, png

I'm trying to save a PNG image by copying from an other existing one, and using **imagepng** function, but the saved file has its size increased.
[Here is the initial image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx1q8.png)

```
$destWidth = 1920;
$destHeight = 1080;

$srcWidth = 1920;
$srcHeight = 1080;

// im.png : 399,1 ko
// width : 1920
// heigth : 1080
$image = imagecreatefrompng('im.png');

$imageDest = imagecreatetruecolor($destWidth, $destHeight);

imagecopyresampled($imageDest, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destWidth, $destHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

// imnew.png : 857,5 ko
imagepng($imageDest, 'imnew.png');
```

The initial image has 399,1 ko (with 1920x1080).
But the result image has 857,5 ko (still 1920x1080).
Why ? And is there any solution to not increase the size ?

Comment: Truecolor images take up more space than indexed PNGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to store an image in a PNG file. The method used must differ between your original and the image saved by PHP. See:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110

If you look in the manual where [imagepng()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) is documented you can see that PHP also has some options. For instance the `$quality` parameter. This is one way of making the file smaller.

With [imagetruecolortopalette()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) you can try to reduce the color depth of the image. This can also make the output file smaller.

Not all methods to make images smaller, that are supported by the PNG file format, are supported by PHP.

Comment: But I still don't know why getting such a big size by using my method. 
I have already tried with others PNG images and the size didn't change at all.
With this image in particular there is a problem.

Comment: I would have to have the original image to say more about it. You've given the code, but without the image I can't say what aspect of the image has changed.

Comment: Well there is now a link to the image in the original post.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is a 8-bit color image which you turn into a 24-bit color image with your code. So, try using `imagetruecolortopalette()` or use `imagecreate()` instead of `imagecreatetruecolor()`.

Comment: Ok I tried `imagetruecolortopalette($imageDest, False, 255)` then the size is now 366,5 ko.
I also tried `imagecreate($destWidth, $destHeight)` and the size is 403,7 ko.
It seems that it solves my problem, thanks.